# Close QWebEngineProcess.exe

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebengine, qwebengineview

I have a problem that, after closing a `QDialog` with web content, the QWebEngineProcess.exe process is not closing.

Here is a minimal example:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QWebEngineView>
#include <QWebEngineSettings>
#include <QDialog>
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QLayout>
#include <QtGui>
#include <QPushButton>

class Dialog : public QDialog
{
public:
    Dialog() : QDialog(nullptr)
    {
        resize(512, 512);
        setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);
        auto verticalLayout = new QVBoxLayout(this);
        verticalLayout->setSpacing(0);
        verticalLayout->setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);

        m_webView = new QWebEngineView(this);
        verticalLayout->addWidget(m_webView);
    }

    void openPage(const QUrl& url)
    {
        m_webView->setUrl(url);
    }

private:
    QWebEngineView* m_webView;
};


class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
public:
    MainWindow() : QMainWindow(nullptr)
    {
        resize(512, 512);
        QPushButton* btn = new QPushButton("open web dialog", this);
        connect(btn, &QPushButton::clicked, [this] ()
                {
                    if (m_dialog == nullptr)
                    {
                        m_dialog = new Dialog();
                        m_dialog->openPage(QUrl("https://www.qt.io"));
                        m_dialog->show();
                    }
                });
    }

private:
    QPointer<Dialog> m_dialog;

};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication::setOrganizationName("QtExamples");
    QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);

    QApplication app(argc, argv);

    MainWindow window;
    window.show();

    return app.exec();
}
```

I'm expecting that, after the dialog is closed, QWebEngineProcess.exe will be closed too, because I'm not using webengine anymore.

P.S. During opening WebPage, I have 2 QWebEngineProcess.exe. One is disappearing, but the second one left.

Comment: Does `QtWebEngineProcess.exe` stay even after you close the app (not just the Dialog)?

Answer (score 0):

For any `QObject` instances (such as `QDialog` and `QWebEngineView`), [the destructor of a parent object destroys all child objects](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qobject.html#QObject). This means, for every object you `new`, it must either have a parent, or you must delete it manually, otherwise you are creating a leak and objects will remain open (not deleted).

You are creating a `QWebEngineView` object with the correct parent, but the parent (the `Dialog`) doesn't have a parent (you initialize the parent to `nullptr`). This means the `Dialog` would delete the `QWebEngineView`, except it never is deleted itself.

To fix it, either delete the `Dialog` (stored in `m_dialog`) manually in the `MainWindow` destructor (not recommended), or initialize it correctly with the `MainWindow` as its parent.

This may also be related to a [bug in Qt 5.11 and 5.12](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-69030). If this is the problem, the recommended solution is to add `QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_UseOpenGLES);` at the top of your `main()` function (before declaring the `QApplication`).

Comment: I think `setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose);` do clean up. At least `~Dialog` called and on second click `m_dialog == nullptr`. Anyway, even providing parent doesn't remove QtWebEngineProcess.exe

Comment: @Holiday I added an alternate idea, please check if that fixes your problem.

Comment: Unfortunately no. I'm using Qt  5.14.2. with QWebEngine 5.15.2. Additionally tested on Qt 5.15.2
Looks like I'll need to dig inside Qt code